# Efficient way to find divisibility

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

Professor says this isn't a efficient algorithm to check whether the number is divisible by a number from 100,000-150,000. I'm having trouble finding a better way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
unsigned short divisibility_check(unsigned long n) {
    unsigned long i;
    for (i = 100000; i <= 150000; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You could compute a look-up table in advance and just use that. *O(1)* time then! To keep it compact you could express that as a series of 1/0 bits.

Comment: Which is it, 100000-150000 or 1000000-1500000? That's the first problem to solve. Then you might consider eliminating some edge cases. Getting much more efficient would require some higher math, like precomputing all the prime divisors of your set.

Comment: 100K-150K whoops

Comment: There is a few rules to shortcut this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule

Comment: Step 1: build a prime sieve up to 150k; step 2: find the prime factors of n up to 150k; step 3: find a subset of the prime factors of which the product is between 100k and 150k (again using a sieve up to 150k).

Comment: I' confused, I found a function to generate the sieve between 100k-150k. So it's only necessary to compare with these numbers?

Comment: No, you need the whole sieve from 2 up to 150k. Then you use it to find the factors of n up to 150k. Then you combine these factors to try and make a product between 100k and 150k. It's three seperate steps, but they are all relatively simple and fast.

Comment: How big can n be? Do you need to make it efficient allowing precomputation before calling the function or can only edit code of that funcition?

Comment: n can be a very large number, 150k is not the maximum n value. just highest value we are checking for divisibility

Comment: is `long` 32 or 64 bits on your platform?

Comment: I believe 64 bit. I am working in 64-bit ubuntu

Comment: Here's a hint. If the `n` is odd, it's not going to be divisible by an even number.

Comment: If `n < 100,000` it won't be divisible. If `100,000 <= n <= 150,000` it is divisible.
(this a first check to remove 150k (or 300k if you manage negative numbers) really fast)

Also, you should use `int i` instead of `unsigned long i`

Comment: If we assume that a long is 32 bit, Nominal Animal's answer could be what your professor is looking for. Or more precisely: under 100k -> false, 100k ~ 150k -> true, 150k ~ 200k -> false, over 200k -> check range n/150k to n/100k. For the maximum n=2^32-1 the range is 28,634 ~ 42,949, so that's always less than 30% of the original range. If a long is 64 bit, then above n=1.5E+10 we're back to checking the range 100k to 150k.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you need to find whether a positive integer *K* is divisible by a number between 100,000 and 150,000, and it is such a rare operation, that doing precalculations is just not worth the processor time or memory used.

If *K* < 100,000, it cannot be divisible by a number between 100,000 and 150,000.

If 100,000 ≤ *K* ≤ 150,000, it is divisible by itself. It is up to you to decide whether this counts or not.

For a *K* > 150,000 to be divisible by *M*, with 100,000 ≤ *M* ≤ 150,000, *K* must also be divisible by *L* = *K* / *M*. This is because *K* = *L* × *M*, and all three are positive integers. So, you only need to test the divisibility of *K* by a set of *L*, where ⌊ *K* / 150,000 ⌋ ≤ *L* ≤ ⌊ *K* / 100,000 ⌋.

However, that set of *L*s becomes larger than the set of possible *M*s when K > = 15,000,000,000. Then it is again less work to just test *K* for divisibility against each *M*, much like OP's code is now.

---

When implementing this as a program, the most important thing in practice is, surprisingly, the comments you add.  Do not write comments that describe what the code does; write comments that explain the model or algorithm you are trying to implement (say, at the function level), and your intent of what each small block of code should accomplish.

In this particular case, you should probably add a comment to each `if` clause, explaining your reasoning, much like I did above.

Beginner programmers often omit comments completely.  It is unfortunate, because writing good comments is a hard habit to pick up afterwards.  It is definitely a good idea to learn to comment your code (as I described above -- the comments that describe what the code does are less than useful; more noise than help), and keep honing your skill on that.

A programmer whose code is maintainable, is worth ten geniuses who produce write-only code.  This is because all code has bugs, because humans make errors.  To be an efficient developer, your code must be maintainable.  Otherwise you're forced to rewrite each buggy part from scratch, wasting a lot of time.  And, as you can see above, "optimization" at the algorithmic level, i.e. thinking about *how to avoid having to do work*, yields much better results than trying to optimize your loops or something like that.  (You'll find in real life that surprisingly often, optimizing a loop in the proper way, removes the loop completely.)

Even in exercises, proper comments may be the difference between *"no points, this doesn't work"* and *"okay, I'll give you partial credit for this one, because you had a typo/off-by-one bug/thinko on line N, but otherwise your solution would have worked"*.

---

As [bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128885/1475978) did not understand how the above leads to a "naive_with_checks" function, I'll show it implemented here.

For ease of testing, I'll show a complete test program. Supply the range of integers to test, and the range of divisors accepted, as parameters to the program (i.e. `thisprogram 1 500000 100000 150000` to duplicate bolov's tests).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int is_divisible(const uint64_t  number,
                 const uint64_t  minimum_divisor,
                 const uint64_t  maximum_divisor)
{
    uint64_t divisor, minimum_result, maximum_result, result;

    if (number < minimum_divisor) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (number <= maximum_divisor) {
        /* Number itself is a valid divisor. */
        return 1;
    }

    minimum_result = number / maximum_divisor;
    if (minimum_result < 2) {
        minimum_result = 2;
    }

    maximum_result = number / minimum_divisor;
    if (maximum_result < minimum_result) {
        maximum_result = minimum_result;
    }

    if (maximum_result - minimum_result > maximum_divisor - minimum_divisor) {
        /* The number is so large that it is the least amount of work
           to check each possible divisor. */
        for (divisor = minimum_divisor; divisor <= maximum_divisor; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;

    } else {
        /* There are fewer possible results than divisors,
           so we check the results instead. */

        for (result = minimum_result; result <= maximum_result; result++) {
            if (number % result == 0) {
                divisor = number / result;
                if (divisor >= minimum_divisor && divisor <= maximum_divisor) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

int parse_u64(const char *s, uint64_t *to)
{
    unsigned long long  value;
    const char         *end;

    /* Empty strings are not valid. */
    if (s == NULL || *s == '\0')
        return -1;

    /* Parse as unsigned long long. */
    end = s;
    errno = 0;
    value = strtoull(s, (char **)(&end), 0);
    if (errno == ERANGE)
        return -1;
    if (end == s)
        return -1;

    /* Overflow? */
    if (value > UINT64_MAX)
        return -1;

    /* Skip trailing whitespace. */
    while (isspace((unsigned char)(*end)))
        end++;

    /* If the string does not end here, it has garbage in it. */
    if (*end != '\0')
        return -1;

    if (to)
        *to = (uint64_t)value;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t kmin, kmax, dmin, dmax, k, count;

    if (argc != 5) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help | help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s MIN MAX MIN_DIVISOR MAX_DIVISOR\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program counts which positive integers between MIN and MAX,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "inclusive, are divisible by MIN_DIVISOR to MAX_DIVISOR, inclusive.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* Use current locale. This may change which codes isspace() considers whitespace. */
    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support your current locale.\n");

    if (parse_u64(argv[1], &kmin) || kmin < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid minimum positive integer to test.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (parse_u64(argv[2], &kmax) || kmax < kmin || kmax >= UINT64_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid maximum positive integer to test.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (parse_u64(argv[3], &dmin) || dmin < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid minimum divisor to test for.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (parse_u64(argv[4], &dmax) || dmax < dmin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid maximum divisor to test for.\n", argv[4]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    count = 0;
    for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++)
        count += is_divisible(k, dmin, dmax);

    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It is useful to note that the above, running bolov's test, i.e. `thisprogram 1 500000 100000 150000` only takes about 15 ms of wall clock time (13 ms CPU time), median, on a much slower Core i5-7200U processor. For really large numbers, like 280,000,000,000 to 280,000,010,000, the test does the maximum amount of work, and takes about 3.5 seconds per 10,000 numbers on this machine.

In other words, I wouldn't trust bolov's numbers to have any relation to timings for *properly written* test cases.

It is important to note that for any *K* between 1 and 500,000, the same test that bolov says their code measures, the above code does at most *two* divisibility tests to find if *K* is divisible by an integer between 100,000 and 150,000.

This solution is therefore quite efficient. It is definitely acceptable and near-optimal, when the tested *K* are relatively small (say, 32 bit unsigned integers or smaller), or when precomputed tables cannot be used.

Even when precomputed tables can be used, it is unclear if/when [prime factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) becomes faster than the direct checks.  There is certainly a tradeoff in the size and content of the precomputed tables.  bolov claims that it is clearly superior to other methods, but hasn't implemented a proper "naive" divisibility test as shown above, and bases their opinion on experiments on quite small integers (1 to 500,000) that have simple prime decompositions.

As an example, a table of integers 1 to 500,000 pre-checked for divisibility takes only 62500 bytes (43750 bytes for 150,000 to 500,000). With that table, each test takes a small near-constant time (that only depends on memory and cache effects). Extending it to all 32-bit unsigned integers would require 512 GiB (536,870,912 bytes); the table can be stored in a memory-mapped read-only file, to let the OS kernel manage how much of it is mapped to RAM at any time.

Prime decomposition itself, especially using trial division, becomes more expensive than the naive approach when the number of trial divisions exceeds the range of possible divisors (50,000 divisors in this particular case). As there are 13848 primes (if one counts 1 and 2 as primes) between 1 and 150,000, the number of trial divisions can easily approach the number of divisors for sufficiently large input values.

For numbers with many prime factors, the combinatoric phase, finding if any subset of the prime factors multiply to a number between 100,000 and 150,000 is even more problematic. The number of possible combinations grows faster than exponentially.  Without careful checks, this phase alone can do way more work per large input number than just trial division with each possible divisor would be.

(As an example, if you have 16 different prime factors, you already have 65,535 different combinations; more than the number of direct trial divisions. However, all such numbers are larger than 64-bit; the smallest being 2·3·5·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37·41·43·47·53 = 32,589,158,477,190,044,730 which is a 65-bit number.)

There is also the problem of code complexity.  The more complex the code, the harder it is to debug and maintain.

Comment: I think your logic with `L` is flawed. If K = L × M with  `M` and `L` prime numbers, 100,000 ≤ M ≤ 150,000 and L > M then L can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: also, I don't really see the benefits of this answer. You explore an avenue (and even if you are correct) and you conclude that wouldn't be more optimal. But there maybe are other avenues that could result in a more optimal program. For instance there is the option of prime sieves and factorization.

Comment: @bolov: No, you completely misunderstand the answer and the algorithm described. The idea is to use a different approach depending on which range the number to be tested falls into. This means that for a number that is between say 150,000 and 1,000,000 at most 4 test divisions (or rather, modulo and division operations) need to be done.  This approach is quite efficient, and when run on a much slower computer than yours, find the same result at least 500 times faster (taking about 15 milliseconds total, while your own table shows your best effort takes 7320 milliseconds, or 7.32 seconds).

Comment: you are right, I don't understand your algorithm. I will take a look over it when I get some time. Until then I ran your version (indeed it gets the same result as mine) and I got ≅14 ms on my system. I will do some more tests.

Comment: @bolov: That is okay; I apologize if my tone has been overly aggressive.  It is not intentional.  I just want to make sure we do not accidentally or intentionally misinform others.  If it matters, you could consider testing the last 10,000 64-bit integers bar one for divisibility; i.e. from 18,446,744,073,709,541,615 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,614. If you run my program, you'll see that it reports the answer, 2324, in about 3.5 seconds. (My loop won't finish for upper limit of 2⁶⁴-1; will fix.)

Comment: you tone was not a problem, no need to apologise. I want to test for upper limit too. But I think my version would overflow for big numbers when I do the product of factors so I need to investigate. When I fix that I will also post my code.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: There may be more than two small divisors, whose product is within the range; this path of thinking leads to prime decomposition and the possible combinatoric explosion in complexity. (Remember, the "slow" method is not really *that* slow, doing at most 50,000 trial divisions per number; it is suboptimal for numbers smaller than 15,000,000,000 or so, but not necessarily so for numbers larger than that.)

Comment: For the test with the last 10,000 integers in the 64-bit range, I'm getting 3.7 seconds with the naive+checks+inversion method (my own C version) and 6 seconds with the prime factorization method (using C, but with a sieve-like method to find a product of factors in the target range, not bolov's DFS). However, using the range 100k~200k the prime factorization wins 6.9s to 8s, so there is a time and place for both methods to shine :-)

Comment: Actually, with compiler optimizations switched on, the prime factorization is slightly faster than naive+checks+inversion in the test with the last 10,000 integers in the 64-bit range. I'm now getting 3.6 vs 3.5 seconds.

Comment: @m69: Excellent information; I assume you verified the result also. What I am interested in, is finding a way to reliably predict when the factorization method is faster, based on the range of divisors and/or the candidate to be tested. (FWIW, I typically use gcc and `-Wall -O2`.)

Comment: The combinatorics stage of the factorization method isn't as problematic as you might think. E.g. with the sieve method, the number of steps is limited by the size of the sieve, which is max_res/2. The theoretical upper bound is factors * sieve_size, but the real worst case is much smaller. And sieves are very efficient because they don't use expensive operations.

Comment: @m69: Yes, I do realize that. Any number smaller than `limit` has at most `ceil(log(limit)/log(2))` factors in a prime factorization, typically much, much fewer. That means there is no 64-bit unsigned integer with more than 63 factors; if it is odd, it has at most 40 factors. There is also no 64-bit unsigned integer with more than 15 unique factors (because the first 16 primes product is larger). I've just been bitten before by the combinatoric explosion, so I am being careful; that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I've implemented the version with sieve primes and factorization mentioned in the comments by m69 and it is ... way faster than the naive approach. I must admit, I didn't expect this at all.

My notations: `left == 100'000` and `right = 150'000`

- **naive** your version
- **naive_with_checks** your version with simple checks:

  - `if (n < left)` no divisor
  - `else if (n <= right)` divisor
  - `else if (left * 2 >= right && n < left * 2)` divisor
- **factorization** (above checks implemented)

  1. Precompute the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for all primes up to `right`. This time is not measured
  2. factorize `n` (only with the primes from the prev step)
  3. generate all subsets (backtracking, depth first: i.e. generate `p1^0 * p2^0 * p3^0` first, instead of `p1^5` first) with the product `< left` or until the product is in `[left, right]` (found divisor).
- **factorization_opt** optimization of the previous algorithm where the subsets are not generated (no vector of subsets is created). I just pass the current product from one backtracking iteration to the next.
- [Nominal Animal's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53127158/2805305) I have also ran his version on my system with the same range.

I have written the program in `C++` so I won't share it here.

I used `std::uint64_t` as data type and I have checked all numbers from `1` to `500'000` to see if each is divisible by a number in interval `[100'000, 150'000]`. All version reached the same solution: `170'836` numbers with positive results.

The setup:

- Hardware: [Intel Core i7-920](https://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2-66-GHz-4-80-GT-s-Intel-QPI-), 4 cores with HT (all algorithm versions are single threaded), 2.66 GHz (boost 2.93 GHz), 
  8 MB SmartCache; memory: 6 GB DDR3 triple channel.
- Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 (v141), Release x64 mode.

I must also add that I haven't profiled the programs so there is definitely room to improve the implementation. However this is enough here as the idea is to find a better algorithm.

```
version                |  elapsed time (milliseconds)
-----------------------+--------------
naive                  |  167'378 ms (yes, it's thousands separator, aka 167 seconds)
naive_with_checks      |   97'197 ms
factorization          |    7'906 ms
factorization_opt      |    7'320 ms
                       |
Nominal Animal version |       14 ms
```

Some analysis:

For naive vs naive_with_checks: all the numbers in `[1 200'000]` can be solved with just the simple checks. As these represent 40% of all the numbers checked, the naive_with_checks version does roughly 60% of the work naive does. The execution time reflect this as naive_with_checks runtime is ≅58% of the naive version.

The factorization version is a whopping 12.3 times faster. That is indeed impressive. I haven't analyzed the time complexity of the alg.

And the final optimization brings a further 1.08x speedup. This is basically the time gained by removing the creation and copy of the small vectors of subset factors.

For those interested the sieve precomputation which is not included above takes about `1 ms`. And this is the naive implementation from wikipedia, no optimizations whatsoever.

Comment: Can you add times with the sieve calculations included? (Just once, you can keep it static for subsequent calls.)

Comment: Nice. To expand the applicability, I would show results of 500000 random numbers between 1 and 2^64, rather than only 1 to 500000.

Comment: Is the third check not leading to "no divisor" a typo? Btw, you can probably easily incorporate Nominal Animal's suggestion of checking the inverse range (n/right, n/left) instead of (left, right) when n < left*right. (Also, I'd suggest separately timing with random numbers in the 32 and 64 bit range, because it's possible the original task was for 32 bit, in which case the naive code with check and inversion could be more competitive)

Comment: I get completely different results on a much slower Core-i5 7200U. In particular, my own program now shown in my answer only takes 13 ms for the same test, without any precomputed tables. That is 13 ms versus bolov's "optimal" 7320 ms; i.e., mine is supposedly 563 times faster. (Because bolov does not show their code, I cannot run their and compare on my machine.) Therefore, I suggest that everyone takes the claims and figures shown in this answer with a healthy pinch of salt.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Which is the most efficient algorithm will probably depend on whether you interpret long as 32 or 64-bit, and how you test it; I suspect the inversion could be fastest for the 32-bit range, and that could be what the OP's professor was looking for. For the 64-bit range, combining all the ideas is probably fastest.

Comment: @m69: Note that mine uses `uint64_t` like bolov said they did. Mine takes a consistent 0.35ms to 0.40ms on my machine per number to test 64-bit numbers above 15,000,000,000 with smaller numbers being much faster to test (down to 0.000026ms per number below 500,000), and my machine is slower than bolov's. There is *no proof* or even any indication (yet!) that integer factorization performs better than that for large numbers. All we have, right now (until bolov runs further tests), is that for numbers below 500,000, mine is over two of orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive method with primes. The idea here is that if a number is divisible by a number between 100000 and 150000, there is a path of reducing by division the product of only relevant primes that will pass through a state in the target range. (Note: the code below is meant for numbers greater than 100000*150000). In my testing, I could not find an instance where the stack performed over 600 iterations.

```py
# Euler sieve
def getPrimes():
  n = 150000
  a = (n+1) * [None]
  ps = ([],[])
  s = []
  p = 1

  while (p < n):
    p = p + 1

    if not a[p]:
      s.append(p)
      # Save primes less
      # than half
      # of 150000, the only
      # ones needed to construct
      # our candidates.
      if p < 75000:
        ps[0].append(p);
      # Save primes between
      # 100000 and 150000
      # in case our candidate
      # is prime.
      elif p > 100000:
        ps[1].append(p)

      limit = n / p
      new_s = []

      for i in s:
        j = i
        while j <= limit:
          new_s.append(j)
          a[j*p] = True
          j = j * p
      s = new_s

  return ps

ps1, ps2 = getPrimes()

def f(n):
  # Prime candidate
  for p in ps2:
    if not (n % p):
      return True

  # (primes, prime_counts)
  ds = ([],[])
  prod = 1
  # Prepare only prime
  # factors that could
  # construct a composite
  # candidate.
  for p in ps1:
    while not (n % p):
      prod *= p
      if (not ds[0] or ds[0][-1] != p):
        ds[0].append(p)
        ds[1].append(1)
      else:
        ds[1][-1] += 1
      n /= p

  # Reduce the primes product to
  # a state where it's between
  # our target range.
  stack = [(prod,0)]

  while stack:
    prod, i = stack.pop()

    # No point in reducing further
    if prod < 100000:
      continue
    # Exit early
    elif prod <= 150000:
      return True
    # Try reducing the product
    # by different prime powers
    # one prime at a time
    if i < len(ds[0]):
      for p in xrange(ds[1][i] + 1):
        stack.append((prod / ds[0][i]**p, i + 1))

  return False
```

Output:

```py
c = 0

for ii in xrange(1099511627776, 1099511628776):
  f_i = f(ii)

  if f_i:
    c += 1

print c # 239
```

Comment: The question is in C, though.

Comment: @NominalAnimal help! :) I don't know C :(

Comment: I converted it to C, and it runs in about 1200 ms (1.2 seconds) on my machine. (A bit slower than mine, which runs in 13 ms.) I put the code [here](https://pastebin.com/eA7gxPYD) on PasteBin; feel free to copy it to your answer or not, or do with it anything you wish. I consider it yours; I just translated it to C, and converted the tail recursion to a loop. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thank you very much! But please run the tests on the larger numbers. Clearly, yours is more efficient for smaller ones.

Comment: Problem: For n = `1099511627776` to `1099511628776`, inclusive (2⁴⁰ to 2⁴⁰+10000), yours only finds 14, but there are 239. Hmm...

Comment: @NominalAnimal Maybe there's a flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: Do remember that you can always compare your solution to the "slow method" (just try dividing by each integer between 100,000 and 150,000), for really large integers; all methods should find the same number of divisible numbers. For example, I checked that 239 using awk also: `awk 'BEGIN { n = 0; for (i = 1099511627776 ; i <= 1099511628776 ; i++) { for (k = 100000; k <= 150000; k++) if (!(i % k)) break; if (k <= 150000) n++; } print n }'`. I'm quite suspicious/critical of even my own code :)

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, here's what I had in mind when I posted my comment about using prime factorization. Compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -O3 -m64 -march=haswell` this is slightly faster than the naive method with checks and inversion when tested with the last 10,000 integers in the 64-bit range (3.469 vs 3.624 seconds).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void eratosthenes(bool *ptr, uint64_t size) {
    memset(ptr, true, size);
    for (uint64_t i = 2; i * i < size; i++) {
        if (ptr[i]) {
            for (uint64_t j = i * i; j < size; j += i) {
                ptr[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool divisible(uint64_t n, uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    /* check for trivial cases first                                    */
    if (n < a) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n <= b) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n < 2 * a) {
        return false;
    }

    /* Inversion: use range n/b ~ n/a; see Nominal Animal's answer      */
    if (n < a * b) {
        uint64_t c = a;
        a = (n + b - 1) / b; // n/b rounded up
        b = n / c;
    }

    /* Create prime sieve when first called, or re-calculate it when    */
    /* called with a higher value of b; place before inversion in case  */
    /* of a large sequential test, to avoid repeated re-calculation.    */
    static bool *prime = NULL;
    static uint64_t prime_size = 0;
    if (prime_size <= b) {
        prime_size = b + 1;
        prime = realloc(prime, prime_size * sizeof(bool));
        if (!prime) {
            printf("Out of memory!\n");
            return false;
        }
        eratosthenes(prime, prime_size);
    }

    /* Factorize n into prime factors up to b, using trial division;    */
    /* there are more efficient but also more complex ways to do this.  */
    /* You could return here, if a factor in the range a~b is found.    */
    static uint64_t factor[63];
    uint8_t factors = 0;
    for (uint64_t i = 2; i <= n && i <= b; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            while (n % i == 0) {
                factor[factors++] = i;
                n /= i;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Prepare divisor sieve when first called, or re-allocate it when  */
    /* called with a higher value of b; in a higher-level language, you */
    /* would probably use a different data structure for this, because  */
    /* this method iterates repeatedly over a potentially sparse array. */
    static bool *divisor = NULL;
    static uint64_t div_size = 0;
    if (div_size <= b / 2) {
        div_size = b / 2 + 1;
        divisor = realloc(divisor, div_size * sizeof(bool));
        if (!divisor) {
            printf("Out of memory!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    memset(divisor, false, div_size);
    divisor[1] = true;
    uint64_t max = 1;

    /* Iterate over each prime factor, and for every divisor already in */
    /* the sieve, add the product of the divisor and the factor, up to  */
    /* the value b/2. If the product is in the range a~b, return true.  */
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < factors; i++) {
        for (uint64_t j = max; j > 0; j--) {
            if (divisor[j]) {
                uint64_t product = factor[i] * j;
                if (product >= a && product <= b) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (product < div_size) {
                    divisor[product] = true;
                    if (product > max) {
                        max = product;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t count = 0;
    for (uint64_t n = 18446744073709541615LLU; n <= 18446744073709551614LLU; n++) {
        if (divisible(n, 100000, 150000)) ++count;
    }
    printf("%llu", count);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the naive + checks + inversion implementation I compared it with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool divisible(uint64_t n, uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    if (n < a) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n <= b) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n < 2 * a) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n < a * b) {
        uint64_t c = a;
        a = (n + b - 1) / b;
        b = n  / c;
    }
    while (a <= b) {
        if (n % a++ == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t count = 0;
    for (uint64_t n = 18446744073709541615LLU; n <= 18446744073709551614LLU; n++) {
        if (divisible(n, 100000, 150000)) ++count;
    }
    printf("%llu", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting; especially the divisor table (that seems to avoid the combinatoric explosion my own implementations might suffer from). If you add my `parse_u64()` and modify `main()` to match, it is easier to compare implementations at random ranges; in bash with awk using `progs=(./na ./m69) ; range=($(awk 'BEGIN { srand(); imax = rand()*18446744073709551616.0; dmin = 1 + rand()*1000000000; printf "%.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f\n", imax-9999, imax, dmin, dmin+9999 }')) ; for prog in "${progs[@]}" ; do printf '=====\n%s %s %s %s %s:\n' "$prog" "${range[@]}" ; time "$prog" "${range[@]}" ; done
`.

Comment: Unfortunately, such random testing (ten thousand 64-bit candidates, and ten thousand divisors under 1,000,000,000) indicates the no-divisors case may take a very, very long time to resolve using your approach. Could you please verify?

Comment: @NominalAnimal This code is more or less proof-of-concept, there is a lot of room for improvement; e.g. the divisor sieve goes up to b/2 in case there's a factor 2; however, if there's no factor 2, you can limit it to b/3, and if there's no factor 3, you can limit it to b/5, ... In fact, if the smallest factor is greater than sqrt(b), and there's no factor in the range a~b, then there can be no divisor in the range. This takes care of all primes larger than b, and all compounds with only factors greater than b.

Comment: I know; my point is that just because the approach works well for one set of inputs, does not mean that the approach is acceptable in general. Even a proof-of-concept should be written complete enough to test with essentially random inputs. As an example, test your code for divisors `25470124` to `25480123`, inclusive; with candidate numbers between `3139846159714339328` and `3139846159714349568`, inclusive. There is exactly one, `25478873`×`123233321965` = `3139846159714345445`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Well, that took 444 seconds :-) But then, the complexity of the factorization method is very much related to the value of b, not the width of the range a~b. It's competitive for 100k-150k, but not for 50k ranges that are much higher. (I still have to wrap my head around גלעד ברקן's version, though.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal that's a good point. When the divisor upper bound is significantly greater than what OP asked for, the prime method obliges a much larger pool of primes.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Indeed. However, as you widen the range a~b, the trial division method slows down, so there's a line somewhere where they are equally fast. Or slow :-)

Comment: Don't forget that divisibility testing is kind of the other face of the same coin to primality testing, and we know from the efforts of untold mathematicians how hard that is. So, it should not be any surprise that "simple divisibility testing" is complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution with a sieve cache. If you call the `divisibility_check` function for many numbers in a sequence, this should be very efficient:

```
#include <string.h>

int divisibility_check_sieve(unsigned long n) {
    static unsigned long sieve_min = 1, sieve_max;
    static unsigned char sieve[1 << 19]; /* 1/2 megabyte */
    if (n < sieve_min || n > sieve_max) {
        sieve_min = n & ~(sizeof(sieve) - 1);
        sieve_max = sieve_min + sizeof(sieve) - 1;
        memset(sieve, 1, sizeof sieve);
        for (unsigned long m = 100000; m <= 150000; m++) {
            unsigned long i = sieve_min % m;
            if (i != 0)
                i = m - i;
            for (; i < sizeof sieve; i += m) {
                sieve[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return sieve[n - sieve_min];
}
```

Here is a comparative benchmark:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int divisibility_check_naive(unsigned long n) {
    for (unsigned long i = 100000; i <= 150000; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int divisibility_check_small(unsigned long n) {
    unsigned long i, min = n / 150000, max = n / 100000;
    min += (min == 0);
    max += (max == 0);
    if (max - min > 150000 - 100000) {
        for (i = 100000; i <= 150000; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                unsigned long div = n / i;
                if (div >= 100000 && div <= 150000)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}

int divisibility_check_sieve(unsigned long n) {
    static unsigned long sieve_min = 1, sieve_max;
    static unsigned char sieve[1 << 19]; /* 1/2 megabyte */
    if (n < sieve_min || n > sieve_max) {
        sieve_min = n & ~(sizeof(sieve) - 1);
        sieve_max = sieve_min + sizeof(sieve) - 1;
        memset(sieve, 1, sizeof sieve);
        for (unsigned long m = 100000; m <= 150000; m++) {
            unsigned long i = sieve_min % m;
            if (i != 0)
                i = m - i;
            for (; i < sizeof sieve; i += m) {
                sieve[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return sieve[n - sieve_min];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long n, count = 0, lmin, lmax, range[2] = { 1, 500000 };
    int pos = 0, naive = 0, small = 0, sieve = 1;
    clock_t t;
    char *p;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        n = strtoul(argv[i], &p, 0);
        if (*p == '\0' && pos < 2)
            range[pos++] = n;
        else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "naive"))
            naive = 1;
        else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "small"))
            small = 1;
        else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "sieve"))
            sieve = 1;
        else
            printf("invalid argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    lmin = range[0];
    lmax = range[1] + 1;
    if (naive) {
        t = clock();
        for (count = 0, n = lmin; n != lmax; n++) {
            count += divisibility_check_naive(n);
        }
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("naive: [%lu..%lu] -> %lu non-divisible numbers, %10.2fms\n",
               lmin, lmax - 1, count, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    if (small) {
        t = clock();
        for (count = 0, n = lmin; n != lmax; n++) {
            count += divisibility_check_small(n);
        }
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("small: [%lu..%lu] -> %lu non-divisible numbers, %10.2fms\n",
               lmin, lmax - 1, count, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    if (sieve) {
        t = clock();
        for (count = 0, n = lmin; n != lmax; n++) {
            count += divisibility_check_sieve(n);
        }
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("sieve: [%lu..%lu] -> %lu non-divisible numbers, %10.2fms\n",
               lmin, lmax - 1, count, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some run times:

```
naive: [1..500000] -> 329164 non-divisible numbers,  158174.52ms
small: [1..500000] -> 329164 non-divisible numbers,      12.62ms
sieve: [1..500000] -> 329164 non-divisible numbers,       1.35ms
sieve: [0..4294967295] -> 3279784841 non-divisible numbers,    8787.23ms
sieve: [10000000000000000000..10000000001000000000] -> 765978176 non-divisible numbers,    2205.36ms
```

Comment: So this is primarily geared towards the sequential tests we've been using?

Comment: @m69: indeed it is not a generic approach, but a vast improvement if the function happens to be used in a sequential pattern.